# SSH command for search and replace in directories and subdirectories

Tags: search, ssh, replace

These SSH commands work in changing text for several files in a directory

> replace "old-string" "new-String" -- *.ext
>
> replace "old-string" "new-String" -- *
>
> replace "old-string" "new-String" -- filename

however these won't target subdirectories... anybody knows the command to include ALL subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

I think sed is better for this. Your first two examples can be rewritten:

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i s/old-string/new-string/g
find . -type f -name '*.ext' | xargs sed -i s/old-string/new-string/g
```

You can also pipe the results of `find` to your `replace` command, if that is better for you.

Comment: Thanks @Charles unfortunately, it didn't work, throw me an error saying no such file in directory. 

I'm working on a set of php files on different subfolders.